# How to read & write Local MySQL Server 8 from Google Colab with Pyspark?

Tags: python, mysql, pyspark, google-colaboratory

I have been trying but failing to write/read tables from MySQL Server 8.0.19 on localhost on Windows 10 with pyspark from Google colab. There's also a lot of similar questions and with some suggested answers but none of the solutions seem to work here. Here is my code:

```
    <...installations  ...>

        from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

        spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("Word Count")\
        .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/content/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar")\
        .getOrCreate()
```

An here is the connection string:

```
MyjdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc")\
                    .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb?user=testuser&password=pwtest")\
                    .option("dbtable", "collisions")\
                    .option("driver","com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")\
                    .load()
```

I have as well used the `.option("driver","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` but still keep getting this error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o154.load.
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

...
...
...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

From this, I guess that MySQL Sever is not reachable. 
I have Telnetted to port 3306 & it confirmed that MySQL Server is accepting connections from client machine. I have read that running: `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="MySQL Server" action=allow protocol=TCP dir=in localport=3306` will permitting firewall rule for MySQL Server incase it was being blocked, yet no change.

Can somebody help outpy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After about several days of trials I discovered a solution, that is why I am going to answer my own question. I was able to connect using a WAMP server (thanks to @Shubham Jain for suggesting) and as well as without a WAMP server. This answer is without WAMP server.

***Downloaded*** `ngrok` from https://ngrok.com/,
***Unzipped*** it,
***Saved*** it on my local windows,
***Authinticate*** with:
     `./ngrok authtoken xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
(pretty straight forward instructions available on the website)

Still on my local Windows, I copied and ran `ngrok tcp 3306` on the command line

`C:\Users\userMe> ngrok tcp 3306`

and it gave someting like:

```
ngrok by @inconshreveable                                                             
Session Status                online
Account                       userMe (Plan: Free)
Version                       2.3.35
Region                        United States (us)
Web Interface                 http://localhost:4041
Forwarding                    tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io:17992 -> localhost:3306

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

Where `0.tcp.ngrok.io:17992` is the only thing I am interested in and where `3306` is MySQL's and only port I am interested at exposing to the internet to link with my Google Colab.

So, at the end of the day, my PySpark READ connection will look like:

```
jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc")\
                    .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://0.tcp.ngrok.io:17992/mydb?user=testUser&password=pestpw")\
                    .option("dbtable", "pipeLineTable")\
                    .option("driver","com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")\
                    .load();
```

The WRITE connection will be:

```
jdbcDF.write.mode("overwrite")\
    .format("jdbc")\
    .option("url",  f"jdbc:mysql://0.tcp.ngrok.io:17992/mydb")\
    .option("dbtable", "fromGcTable")\
    .option("user", "testUser")\
    .option("password", "testpw")\
    .option("driver","com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")\
    .save()
```

In both connection strings, note the `0.tcp.ngrok.io:17992` that replaces `localhost:3306`

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I install and setup MySQL on Colab

```py
# install, set connection
!apt-get install mysql-server > /dev/null
!service mysql start
!mysql -e "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root'"
!pip -q install PyMySQL
%load_ext sql
%config SqlMagic.feedback=False 
%config SqlMagic.autopandas=True
%sql mysql+pymysql://root:root@/
# query using %sql or %%sql
df = %sql SELECT Host, User, authentication_string FROM mysql.user
df
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect **mysql database installed on your local machine i.e. windows 10 from google colab as localhost instance**.

This is not possible because google colab spins up instance of their own to execute your code, if you want to access your local mysql you need to host it on a server so that it is reachable over the internet.

Otherwise, you can install mysql on colab then use that to run your code for testing.

```
!apt-get -y install mysql-server
```

then configure it on instance to use

Answer (score 0):

Solution retried in colab in 2021, this version currently works:

```py
import pymysql
link=pymysql.connect(
   host="xx.tcp.ngrok.io",    
   user="userName", 
   password="userPassword",
   db="dbName", 
   charset="utf8",
   port=xxxxx
   )
```